# Netbeans Ant environment variables

Tags: macos, netbeans, ant, environment-variables

I am having a problem accessing environment variables in a netbeans build.xml ant script. Basically, when I use this code:

```
<target name="-pre-jar">

    <property environment="env"/>

    <echo message="${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
    <echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>

</target>
```

I receive output as follows:

```
compile:
${env.ANT_HOME}
${env.JAVA_HOME}
```

This is a problem because I need to access those filepaths later in the script. Also, I am sure that those two are defined as environment variables.  Here is some proof from my terminal:

```
Lukas-Rezeks-MacBook-Pro:ant lukas$ echo $JAVA_HOME - $ANT_HOME
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home - /ant
```

Am I doing something wrong in the ant build scripts variable declaration, or am I missing something obvious? Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Oh my fault. The echo statements are in "-pre-jar" so that the problem is not how you call it from "compile".

Comment: Not exactly "solved" per-say, but I did figure out a way around it. Ant home I just set in netbeans so it did it automatically, and java home was actually imported elsewhere. Verbose mode didn't exactly clear anything up, so I started looking for some other way.  Thanks for all your help though, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Well, I recommend you double check your system environment varibles. I am using Linux and there are a lot of differences between Linux and Mac OS so I can't do more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

outside your target,

OR use "depends=" instead of "antcall" in your compile task.

I did the following test on my Linux:

```
<target name="pre-jar">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <echo message="${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
    <echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <antcall target="pre-jar" />
    <echo message="${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
    <echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

and when I ran "ant compile" I got the following:

> compile:
>
> pre-jar:
>       [echo] /opt/apache-ant-1.8.2
>       [echo] /opt/jdk1.7.0
>       [echo] ${env.ANT_HOME}
>       [echo] ${env.JAVA_HOME}

and when I used depends="pre-jar", the result was:

> pre-jar:
>       [echo] /opt/apache-ant-1.8.2
>       [echo] /opt/jdk1.7.0
>
> compile:
>       [echo] /opt/apache-ant-1.8.2
>       [echo] /opt/jdk1.7.0

when I put  outside any target, the result was:

> compile:
>
> pre-jar:
>       [echo] /opt/apache-ant-1.8.2
>       [echo] /opt/jdk1.7.0
>       [echo] /opt/apache-ant-1.8.2
>       [echo] /opt/jdk1.7.0

Comment: No such luck, totally copied your code and still get the var name printing out...

Comment: For the example from my answer, try to run ant with verbose mode like: "ant -v pre-jar" and then post the output here. And check this: http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/lt-property-environment-env-gt-doesn-t-pick-up-an-environment-variable-td1353518.html

Answer (score 0):

This is completely working for me on my OSX system:

```
[mike@numbersix ~/temp]$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 3 2011
[mike@numbersix ~/temp]$ echo $JAVA_HOME - $ANT_HOME
/Library/Java/Home - /usr/share/ant
[mike@numbersix ~/temp]$ cat build.xml 
<project name="blah">
    <target name="foo">
        <property environment="env"/>

        <echo message="${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
        <echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
    </target>
</project>
[mike@numbersix ~/temp]$ ant foo
Buildfile: /Users/mike/temp/build.xml

foo:
     [echo] /usr/share/ant
     [echo] /Library/Java/Home

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: from SuperTron's output, he got the problem when calling "pre-jar" from another target named "compile". If he uses <antcall> then he can't get the property in compile, while "depends" works.

Comment: Stupid Netbeans nbbuild.xml stuff.  :P

Comment: Actually I am wrong with my answer. See my comment below the question... That's weird.