# How do I know the Glassfish install directory from build.xml?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, glassfish-4

I'm trying to build a few java projects in Netbeans 8 and to add some targets in their respective build.xml file (Ant targets). All my projects need to know where I installed GlassFish 4.1 web server.

I've seen in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003891/netbeans-ant-environment-variables) an example to env.JAVA_HOME.

How do I get a look of all the envrimonent variables that netbeans hold? specifically I'm looking for GLASSFISH_INSTALL_DIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it this way:
put in ~/.profile:

```
export GF_HOME=path/to/glassfish/
```

then add to build.xml (in the target of your choice):

```
<property environment="env"/>
<target name="myTarget"> 
    <copy flatten="true" file="${dist.jar}"  todir="${env.GF_HOME}/domains/domain1/lib/"/>
</target>
```

note: the flatten parameter was required due to a bug in NetBeans 8.0.1 (see my bug [report])[1](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249027)