# Ant: how to add a path in System Path

Tags: java, ant

Hi Java and Ant Gurus,

I have found out that in ant build (etc...) you can display the system path like this: ${$sysenv:PATH}. My question is, how do we add a path on this variable on the build.xml? Or is it even possible? I have searched for hours already but no luck :( Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to make your Ant script permanently modify the existing PATH variable in your system's environment? This is probably not a great idea. I recommend simply referencing the existing PATH value and create a new property within the script that adds to it.

Comment: @CAustin... oh I see. I actually wanted ant to use another a modified system path but not modify the original one. but I guess its not a straight forward thing. but thanks.

Comment: If you just need Ant to retrieve the value of an environment variable on your system, you can use the `property` task with the `environment` attribute like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003891/netbeans-ant-environment-variables